# OSError: cannot load library '/opt/homebrew/lib/libsndfile.dylib': dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/libsndfile.dylib, 0x0002)

Tags: python, conda, librosa

I was using librosa with conda virtual environment in MAC M1 silicon machine. But it doesn't allow to run even `import librosa` code snippet and popping up this error message.

`OSError: cannot load library '/opt/homebrew/lib/libsndfile.dylib': dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/libsndfile.dylib, 0x0002): tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/libsndfile.dylib' (no such file)`

what would be the error I made

Answer (score 0):

This error popped up because I had three separate python environment in my M1 machine and python interpreter unable to locate the lib directory and load it to the code.

My advice to any person who will going to refer this question is, If you own a Mac m1 environment, setup only a one Conda environment, if you are having multiple virtual environment it will cause errors since Mac uses swap memory to load libs in python